# How do I write my Express session inside custom middleware?

Tags: node.js, session, express

This is my current code:

```
var express = require('express');
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(_settings.c.WEB_PATH + '/public'));
    app.use(_mods.web.mware.rawBody);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({
            cookie:{ domain:"."+_settings.c.SITE_DOMAIN, maxAge:1440009999},
            secret:'password',
            store: r_store,
            }));
    //other middleware here

});
```

I want to replace the session part with a custom middleware (in another file).
I will take out that session part and put this in:

```
var helper = require('helper.js');
app.use(helper.setSession);
```

In that file, I have this:

```
var express = require('express');
function setSession(req,res,next){
    express.session({
    cookie:{ domain:"."+_settings.c.SITE_DOMAIN, maxAge:1440009999},
    secret:'password',
    store: r_store,
    }) 
    next();
};  
exports.setSession = setSession;
```

However, when I run it, the session isn't connecting.I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what I'm looking at, but I wouldn't think you'd want to run `express.session` every time, no?

Comment: Nope. I only want to run it in certain occasions.

Comment: No, I mean that `express.session` *returns* a middleware function. Here you're calling it every request. You'd need to return the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.use` takes a function (or array of functions) with signature `(err, )req, res(, next)`

`express.session()` returns a function like any other middleware. You're never calling the function.

```
var express = require('express');
function setSession(req, res, next){
  express.session({
    cookie:{ domain:"."+_settings.c.SITE_DOMAIN, maxAge:1440009999},
    secret:'password',
    store: r_store,
  })(req, res, next);
};  
exports.setSession = setSession;
```